# ¿Cómo subir archivo laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero subir un archivo a mi sistema pero me sale este error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: archivo.crear] [URI: archivo/archivo-crear/{codInf}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sysaa\resources\views\archivo\listar.blade.php)

Éstas son mis vistas de donde adjunto el archivo:

```
<tr>
                            <td>{{$i}}</td>
                            <td>{{$normativaMacroproceso->Normativac->tipoNormativa}}</td>
                            <td>{{$normativaMacroproceso->Normativac->numero}}</td>
                            <td>{{$normativaMacroproceso->Normativac->nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{$normativaMacroproceso->Macroproceso->nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{$normativaMacroproceso->Normativac->fecha}}</td>
                            <th><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
                            <td><a href="{{URL::to('normaAuditoria/editar')}}/{{$normativaMacroproceso->codNormMacro}}" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Editar </a>
                            <a href="{{URL::to('archivo/archivo-crear')}}/{{9}}" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Adjuntar </a></td>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
```

Como podrán ver de acá me manda a una ruta que es la siguiente:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'archivo'], function(){
    Route::get('archivo-crear/{codInf}','ArchivoController@crear')->name('archivo.crear');
    Route::post('archivo-registrar','ArchivoController@registrar')->name('archivo.registrar');
    Route::get('archivo','ArchivoController@listar')->name('archivo.listar');
    //Route::get('archivo-crear','ArchivoController@crear')->name('archivo.crear');
    Route::get('archivo-eliminar/{id}','ArchivoController@eliminar')->name('archivo.eliminar');
});
```

y la vista `archivo-crear` es la siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <h5>Cargar archivo</h5>

        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <strong>NOTA: PESO MAXIMO 5 MB</strong>
                </div>
                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => 'archivo.registrar', 'files' => true]) !!}
                    <div class="col-md-6 b-r">

                        {!! Field::file('archivo') !!}
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{$codInf}}" name="codInf">

                        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" value="REGISTRAR">
                        </div>
                        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

                    </div>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Acá está mi controlador con crear, registrar y listar:

```
public function listar(Request $request)
    {
        $archivos = Archivo::Activo()->get();
        return view('archivo.listar', compact('archivos'));
    }

    public function crear(Request $request)
    {
        $codInf = $request->codInf;
        return view('archivo.crear')->with(compact('codInf'));
    }

    public function registrar(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('archivo'))
        {
            $archivo = $request->file('archivo')->store('archivo','public');
            Archivo::create(['nombre' => $archivo, 'codInf' => 0 ]);
            return redirect()->route('archivo.listar')->with('success','Archivo cargado');
        }else
        {
            return redirect()->route('archivo.listar')->with('danger','Debe cargar un archivo');
        }
    }



    public function eliminar($id)
    {
        $archivo = Archivo::Existe($id)->update(['estado' => false]);
        return redirect()->route('archivo.listar')->with('danger','Archivo Eliminado');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, el error hace referencia a esta linea de código :

```
<a href="{{URL::to('archivo/archivo-crear')}}/{{9}}" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Adjuntar </a></td>
```

El error comenta que no puedes generar la ruta "archivo-crear" por que la falta asignar un parámetro que definiste en las rutas, en este caso es {codInf}.

La forma mas correcta de crear rutas en las vistas de laravel es atraves de su helper route() un ejemplo de como quedaria con el helper.

```
<a href="{{ route('archivo.crear' , ['condInf' => 9]) }}" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Adjuntar </a></td>
```

automáticamente el añadirá el id a la ruta y la generara, no lo tienes que imprimir por separado de la ruta como estas haciendo.
Y otra cosilla, estas asignando nombres a las rutas, usalos!

```
Route::get('archivo-crear/{codInf}','ArchivoController@crear')->name('archivo.crear');
```

Ese "->name('archivo.crear')" es el nombre que has de llamar para generar la ruta.

mas información sobre rutas en laravel : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

Te falta especificar el parametro `codInf`, por lo que veo lo estas concatenando fuera y no dentro del `URL::to()`, la solución mas sencilla es editarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('archivo/archivo-crear/9')}}" class="btn btn-white btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Adjuntar </a></td>
```

Por cuestión de buenas practicas te recomiendo seguir la respuesta de @pwron.